# Gedit on Mac doesn't open

Tags: macos, homebrew, open-source

I have an issue with gedit on my Intel iMac 2015 and my MacBook Pro M1. On both OS I tried to install gedit manually and via homebrew and on both it doesn't open at all. I can see that it tries to open it but fails and closes and again immediately. I have no idea why this happens and I even don't get an error message.

Does anyone has the same problem and knows the solution to it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem. Can you provide the error messages? As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what your problem is.

Comment: How do you start gedit - from the terminal?

Comment: I tried both. manually from applications folder and via "open -a gedit"

Comment: @YannickFitch If you launch the binary directly, what does it output?

Comment: @MarcWilson sorry I am not the computer pro. how do I generate that?

Comment: @YannickFitch Open a terminal, run `/Applications/Gedit/Contents/MacOS/gedit`, see if it outputs anything when it crashes.  Make appropriate changes as necessary to that path for capitalization of names.

Comment: @MarcWilson `/Applications/gedit.app/Contents/MacOS/gedit: line 58: /Applications/gedit.app/Contents/MacOS/gedit-bin: Bad CPU type in executable
/Applications/gedit.app/Contents/MacOS/gedit: line 58: /Applications/gedit.app/Contents/MacOS/gedit-bin: Undefined error: 0
/Applications/gedit.app/Contents/MacOS/gedit: line 56: /Applications/gedit.app/Contents/Resources/libexec/gconfd-2: Bad CPU type in executable`

Comment: @YannickFitch Ok, you either have an ARM version installed on the Intel Mac, or an Intel version installed on the ARM Mac.  Which one did you do the test on?

Answer (score 1):

The homebrew version of [gedit](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit) requires XQuartz to run, it will just hang otherwise. The most recent version of XQuartz can be downloaded from the [project website](https://www.xquartz.org/).

Comment: MacPorts has a +quartz variant for `gedit`, although I don't think it's the current version.  There are also macOS native versions available from ftp.gnome.org, but those haven't been updated since 2019.

Comment: @MarcWilson Homebrew has version 42.2.

Comment: But it requires X11?  I went down 3-4 levels of deps and couldn't actually tell.

Comment: @MarcWilson It doesn't have a dependency within Homebrew. But it just hangs if started from Terminal (and throws some X11-related errors when started with any option), works from xterm though.

Comment: I also tried to install it with MacPorts but I can't make all dependencies work (`Error: Failed to build libnice: command execution failed`).

Comment: @nohillside XQuartz didn't solve the problem either.

Comment: @YannickFitch did you kill any running gedit processes? Did you start from xterm?

Comment: @nohillside yeah no processes and I started it in xterm. same problem

Comment: @YannickFitch Do you get any output if you run `gedit -V` in Terminal?

Comment: @nohillside `(gedit:77268): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 09:21:01.837: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(gedit:77268): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 09:21:01.838: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(gedit:77268): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 09:21:01.838: g_signal_handler_disconnect: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed`

Comment: @YannickFitch That's the error I get as well, unless I run gedit from an xterm. Do you get the same error there?